# Why doesn't the double slit experiment disprove general relativity? (or vice-versa for G.R. tests with Q.M.)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, double-slit-experiment, quantum-gravity

I learned that General Relativity and Quantum Mechanics are fundamentally incompatible models of the world, yet we have observations with evidence for both. Thus, I am confused about why we cannot experimentally rule out either theory (or both at the same time).

If we have experiments/tests/observations that show that one is valid in a single case (such as double-slit for Q.M. or gravitational lensing for G.R.), doesn't that immediately provide a counter-example which disproves the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding about what it means for a theory to be correct and what it would take to "disprove"* it. When we say that a physical theory is correct, we do not mean that it exactly describes what is "actually" going in fundamentally in the universe, and we definitely don't mean that it describes everything. Rather, we mean that it accurately makes verifiable predictions within a certain domain of applicability. For more detail on this, I would recommend reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4057.pdf) by Carlo Rovelli on the correctness of Aristotelian physics and [this essay](http://mvellend.recherche.usherbrooke.ca/Asimov_anglosaboteurs.pdf) by Isaac Asimov on degrees of correctness. Now, going back to your question about how we can simultaneously say that quantum mechanics and general relativity are correct, the answer is that they don't make contradictory predictions at the scales at which they are applied. In other words, we only apply quantum mechanics in contexts in which gravitational effects of the system are small enough that we can use a fixed spacetime metric (which [need not be Minkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory_in_curved_spacetime)). Similarly, we only apply general relativity in contexts in quantum mechanical effects are negligible. Of course, there are going to be contexts in which neither of these theories are applicable, in which we will need to develop a theory of quantum gravity.

---

*"(Dis)prove" is more of a mathematical term, and isn't really used in physics.

Answer (score 4):

At the present time there exists no mathematical model that can fit all the available measured  observations/data in physics, what is hopefully called a [Theory of Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything) TOE.

What we have, ever since Newton's time, is a number of good mathematical models that fit the data in specific regions of the variables used to measure the observations, and also, very important, the models are predictive.

Newtonian mechanics could not fit the data for the large length scales of the cosmos, nor be predictive. General Relativity  replaced its inadequacies and has given us the current [Big Bang model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang).

For very small length scales we have discovered the theory of Quantum Mechanics, but have no unified mathematical model with both QM and GR.

So, until, or if, we get a TOE we have to live with it and create specific mathematical models for the overlap region of the variables. It is not possible to rule out theories, the way you imagine.

Comment: My question is a bit more... why is it not possible to rule them out?

Comment: see the other answer by Sandejo

Answer (score 0):

General Relativity (GR) is theory of gravitation and Quantum Mechanics (QM) is theory of matter, or as I would say, theory of measurements (interactions). The first deals with space and time, the second with physical quantities (observables). As Anna already answered, they cannot exclude each other like you suggest in your question.

By the way, it is always good to scrutinize established convictions and ask questions therefore my upvote for your question.